# Two way binding doesn't work if binding is set by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have this dom element with a `{{name}}` binding

```
<div b="{{name}}"></div>
```

I want to access this div and update it's `b` attribute via jquery like so:

`$('div').attr('b', 10)`, and I expect the two way binding to update the property on the according component. But it doesn't work why?

Comment: b="{{name}}" basically binds b attribute to the 'name' in your controller. If you change the value of 'name', ember will automatically take care of syncing it. 2 way binding normally works with input helpers. Ember uses its set/get methods to trigger its binding mechanism. When u use jquery, ember has no way to know that the value has changed. What is ur use case? Using jquery seems like an anti pattern.

Comment: @blessenm I am building a game where you drag stones, I am binding stone state to the dom attribute so whenever I change the state using jquery It should react accordingly. It could be wrong direction with jquery like you said I don't know.

Comment: Directly touching the DOM is not the ember way of doing things. The model should be the source of truth. You use computed properties, observers, bindings or events on models to modify the DOM.

Comment: @blessenm, but I use [greensock](http://greensock.com/gsap) to drag elements, it uses dom to manipulate stuff and I have to act on dom to manipulate the state of dragged objects. Is there a better way to integrate both?

Comment: Well you look into MutationObserver that emits events when attribute values in the DOM changes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe This question may be more suitable in http://discuss.emberjs.com/

Comment: @blessenm, I've solved my problem by giving an id to each dom element and accessing the required model and updating from there, what do you think?

Comment: Well if it works, its a solution. Do add ur answer with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you do binding is so that you can set the value from code and the change is reflected in template/html. You cannot make a change in html/dom using jquery and expect the change to be shown in code/controller!

Comment: right, i removed it! i didn know u were using htmlbars!